# how to send an e-mail automatically when a row is inserted in the database?

Tags: java

I have to develop a application with the following scenario:

1--User create a profil (name,lastname,address....)

2--The information are inserted in the database

3--The administrator should receive an e-mail to be notified by the new profil  ,if the administrator dont 
approve the profil he will delete it.

Is there a way to send automatically an e-mail when a row is inserted in the database?

I'm using java.

Comment: What DB are you using? What have you tried? You can always (programatically) email when the user finishes his registration.

Comment: use Javamail API, http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javamail/index.html

Comment: I imagine the best way to do this would be to send the email from within the application after the DB transaction successfully commits.  Naturally, you'll want to handle errors in a meaningful way in case the DB interaction works but the email interaction fails (leaving you with orphaned DB inserts without notifications).

Answer (score -1):

If you are doing this through a common interface, then I'd suggest putting a seperate call next to the insert routine (between Java and database).

I heard you can do a whole lot of things with triggers in MS SQL, but I was told to keep my hands away from triggers. Made by the devil to make a day turn bad. People that has succesfully mastered triggers will tell you otherwise.

Comment: "I was told to keep my hands away from triggers. Made by the devil to make a day turn bad. People that has succesfully mastered triggers will tell you otherwise." - Do you have anything substantial to support this claim?

Comment: As clearly shown, I have personally been told otherwise. Meaning the person in question must be a person that has mastered triggers. I bow before you Master of Triggers.